# Irregular spacing in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[image: Irregular spacing in Chrome]
On some pages on my companies website that I run, there is recently a spacing difference on chrome. In comparing I also noticed Firefox spaces above that a little different, but that is at least regular and understandable.

This area of the page spacing irregularly on Chrome is generated using PHP so the code is the EXACT same on all pages. If you go to a page from 2016 (2 rows on the bottom of the picture) we're still using the same code, same css, but the gap disappears. If you go the English version of any of the pages, which I wrote the same, just linking to different pages the gap doesn't show up.

I can't find any difference between a 2015 page (3 rows) and a 2016 page (2 rows) that would cause this. I loaded Firefox to use the 3D view and look at it, but it's not there.

example of 1/7 pages in question: [here](http://www.akidc.co.jp/topix2015.11.html)

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this space between code its take space in chrome but not FF please check below image[image]

Comment: I just found the same myself. It was caused by the BOM heading on the files because I'm importing them individually through PHP. It doesn't show up in the page source, but did in the inspector =o=